# align the div's with same class within the same row in css Grid Layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to align some div's with same class name in a row using css grid layout. when i tried all div are aligned in top of another one. How to achieve this using css grid layout.

```
   .front{
        grid-area: front;
    }
    .accountcontainer{
        display: grid;
        margin: 0 10px;
        background: #ffffff;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "front   front   front  front";
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Show us what effort have you made so far by adding the problematic code.

Comment: @Highdef, i add the css what i tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `grid-area`

Just specify the `grid-row` for that class.

**Note** the number of divs with that class **MUST** be the same as (or less than) the number of columns.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: rows;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.item {
  height: 60px;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item.front {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

.front {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item front">1</div>
  <div class="item front">2</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item front">3</div>
  <div class="item front">4</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```